# Jquery ui panel/portlet plugin solution

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have been trying to find some solution which is based on pure jquery ui.
I need a portlet plugin which can drag n drop n collapse and close .. like [holsee.ui.portlets](https://github.com/holsee/holsee.ui.portlets).

I found a ref here https://github.com/idlesign/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.panel.js
But i could not make it to work although it seems to have all functions i need.

Can someone point me into right direction ?
I tried using above experimental jquery.ui.panel.js and css but no luck.
See code below.

**[See JSFIDDLE HERE:](http://jsfiddle.net/bababalcksheep/2VmyH/)**

After adding the following 
jquery.ui.panel.js
jquery.ui.panel.css

```
<div class="panel"> test panel </div>
$(".panel").panel();
```

But No panel is shown ? Just text.
I think my `<div class="panel"> test panel </div>` syntax is incomplete may be.

Answer (score 0):

Ok Found The solution @ [https://github.com/henryyan/jquery-ui-portlet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTyO1.png)

Its chinese though but should not be hard to get.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qTyO1.png): [image]https://github.com/henryyan/jquery-ui-portlet